# SQL - get top row of each group in a table

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a sql table with the following data:

```
CaseKey    CaseStatus    ParcelKey    Year       Status
-------    ----------    ---------    -------    ------
8866       Open          11901        2024/25    STOP
8866       Open          11901        2023/24    FILE
8866       Open          11901        2022/23    FILE
8866       Open          11901        2021/22    FILE
8866       Open          11901        2020/21    FILE
8866       Open          11901        2019/20    SETT
8866       Open          11901        2018/19    SETT
8866       Open          11901        2017/18    SETT
8866       Open          11902        2024/25    STOP
8866       Open          11902        2023/24    FILE
8866       Open          11902        2022/23    FILE
8866       Open          11902        2021/22    FILE
8866       Open          11902        2020/21    FILE
8866       Open          11902        2019/20    FILE
8866       Open          11902        2018/19    FILE
8866       Open          11902        2017/18    FILE
8866       Open          16451        2024/25    FILE
8866       Open          16451        2023/24    FILE
8866       Open          16452        2024/25    FILE
8866       Open          16452        2023/24    FILE
```

And I need the resulting table to look like this:

```
CaseKey    CaseStatus    ParcelKey    Year       Status
-------    ----------    ---------    -------    ------
8866       Open          11901        2024/25    STOP
8866       Open          11902        2024/25    STOP
8866       Open          16451        2024/25    FILE
8866       Open          16452        2024/25    FILE
```

The script needs to select the most recent year for each ParcelKey group.  I tried this script in ssms:

```
create table #TopRecord
(
    CaseKey int,
    CaseStatus Varchar(30),
    ParcelKey int,
    TaxYear Varchar(7),
    YearStatus Varchar(30)
)
INSERT INTO #TopRecord (CaseKey, CaseStatus, ParcelKey, YearStatus, TaxYear)
SELECT CaseKey, CaseStatus, ParcelKey, YearStatus, TaxYear=MAX(TaxYear)
FROM #tmp
GROUP BY CaseKey, CaseStatus, ParcelKey, YearStatus
ORDER BY CaseKey, CaseStatus, ParcelKey

select * from #TopRecord order by ParcelKey, TaxYear DESC
```

but this is what got generated:

```
CaseKey    CaseStatus    ParcelKey    Year       Status
-------    ----------    ---------    -------    ------
8866       Open          11901        2024/25    STOP
8866       Open          11901        2023/24    FILE
8866       Open          11901        2019/20    SETT
8866       Open          11902        2024/25    STOP
8866       Open          11902        2023/24    FILE
8866       Open          16451        2024/25    FILE
8866       Open          16452        2024/25    FILE
```

I dont understand why I ending up getting 3 records with ParcelKey=11901 and 2 records with ParcelKey=11902.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Your getting multiple rows for each because the year is different.  If you dont want the year and totals for both years combined, remove the year from the select and group by.

Comment: @Brad - If I remove the year from the select, I will not get the year in my resulting table.  And, I am not looking for anything to be "combined".  I need the resulting table to contain the record with the most recent year for each ParcelKey group.

Comment: Then you will get 2 rows for each of those because the data columns you are grouping by are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the below query.

```
select * from ( SELECT     CaseKey,     CaseStatus,     ParcelKey,    TaxYear,    YearStatus,    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY ParcelKey
      ORDER BY CaseKey    ) row_num FROM     TopRecord ) abc  where abc.row_num =1
```

This will give you your desire output.

Comment: I tried your solution and it gave me 1 records per ParcelKey but not the record I was looking for.  I adjusted the ORDER BY to include TaxYear DESC and I got the 4 records I was looking for!  Thank you very much!